# Probability of having at least one coupon out of N types

Tags: probability, random-variables, coupon-collector

I'm facing a question regarding random variables:

> A coupon website has N distinct kinds of coupons. Each selection of a
>   coupon is equally likely and selections are independent. Let $T$ be a random variable representing the number of
>   coupons, $n$, that one should collect until he has at least one coupon
>   of every kind.

I need to determine the probability function $P(T=n)$. How should I approach this question?

Comment: You might be interested in the [**coupon collector problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)